# Extract hex encoded value from response using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

This is part of the response ui2CacheBusterToken\x22\x3a\x22\x7e634CBF4C3DF8E63212283094EA2EA118\x7eC\x22

and need to extract 634CBF4C3DF8E63212283094EA2EA118. Regular expresion extracotr does not work for this case

Comment: what didn't work on regex extractor?

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue with special character "\". Put one more to escape it like "\\" and regex will work.
Check the below snapshot
[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @utkarshg14 if it helped you can accept the answer,see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers